# I am stuck with the next step to setup a dual boot for Windows 7 and Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I am trying to configure my laptop so as to be able to dual boot Windows 7 (64Bit) and Arch Linux.

The laptop on which I want to do that came pre installed with Windows 7. The installation consisted of 2 partitions: the first one 5360 MB in size, obviously being a recovery partition, the second one, using the rest of the harddisk, with Windows itself.

Windows is booted by BIOS through/via MBR.

Here's what I have done so far.

- Went into Windows and shrank the second partition to make room for some linux partitions.
- used Arch Linux live cd to startup Linux environment
- created primary partition `/dev/sda3` (100MB for /boot)
- created extended partition `/dev/sda4`
- created `/dev/sda5 .. /dev/sda10` for `/`, `/home`, `/var`, `swap` and two spare partitions.
- installed Arch linux packages (so that, for example, `/boot/grub` or `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` is existing)

And here's where I am stuck.

I figure I should do something with grub (but am not 100% sure about that) so that it loads either Windows on `/dev/sda2`) or `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` (on `/dev/sda3`) but I have no clue how I would proceed, especially that I am not destroying the Windows booting mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pacman -S os-prober
grub-install /dev/sdX   (do not use partition number)
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And then you should be all set to go, as long as os-prober is installed, it will let grub detect and preserve the windows boot partition.

Note this is NOT for EFI motherboards.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked (though I am not sure if the duplication of `grub-mkconfig grub-mkconfig` is necessary). Also, I specified the absolute path with the -o option (leading `/`).

Comment: typo on my part, sorry. Great to hear you're working now, welcome to Arch :)